# Trying to convert an array of objects to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert the given array

```
[ { slug: 'invoice',
    display: 'Invoice',
    channels: { sms: true, email: false } },
  { slug: 'payment',
    display: 'Payment',
    channels: { sms: true, email: true } },
  { slug: 'manual_reminder',
    display: 'Manual Reminder',
    channels: { sms: true, email: false } },
  { slug: 'automatic_reminder',
    display: 'Automatic Reminder',
    channels: { sms: true, email: false } } ]
```

into this array

```
{"10": 1, "20": 3, "30": 1, "31": 1}
```

I have written the code for converting the above array to this array 
but still I am not getting correct output

```
const NotificationChannels = {
  SMS: 1, // 01
  EMAIL: 2 // 10
  // BOTH: 3
};

const NotificationItems = {
  INVOICE: 10,
  PAYMENT: 20,
  MANUAL_REMINDER: 30,
  AUTOMATIC_REMINDER: 31
};

const getVal = channels => {
  if (channels.sms === true && channels.email === false)
    return NotificationChannels.SMS;

  if (channels.sms === false && channels.email === true)
    return NotificationChannels.EMAIL;

  if (channels.sms === true && channels.email === true)
    return NotificationChannels.EMAIL | NotificationChannels.SMS;
};

let arr = req.body.notification_settings;
console.log(arr);
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i].channels);

  console.log(getVal(arr[i].channels));

  var x = NotificationItems[arr[i].slug.toString().toUpperCase()];
  console.log(x);

  // databaseObject.x = getVal(arr[i].channels);

  // console.log(arr[i].slug.toString().toUpperCase());
  // console.log(arr[i].channels);
}
```

```js
const req = {
 body: {
   notification_settings: [
     { slug: 'invoice', display: 'Invoice', channels: { sms: true, email: false } },
     { slug: 'payment', display: 'Payment', channels: { sms: true, email: true } },
     { slug: 'manual_reminder', display: 'Manual Reminder', channels: { sms: true, email: false } },
     { slug: 'automatic_reminder', display: 'Automatic Reminder', channels: { sms: true, email: false } }
   ]
  }
};

const NotificationChannels = {
  SMS: 1, // 01
  EMAIL: 2 // 10
  // BOTH: 3
};

const NotificationItems = {
  INVOICE: 10,
  PAYMENT: 20,
  MANUAL_REMINDER: 30,
  AUTOMATIC_REMINDER: 31
};

const getVal = channels => {
  if (channels.sms === true && channels.email === false)
    return NotificationChannels.SMS;

  if (channels.sms === false && channels.email === true)
    return NotificationChannels.EMAIL;

  if (channels.sms === true && channels.email === true)
    return NotificationChannels.EMAIL | NotificationChannels.SMS;
};


let arr = req.body.notification_settings;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i].channels);

  console.log(getVal(arr[i].channels));

  var x = NotificationItems[arr[i].slug.toString().toUpperCase()];
  console.log(x);
}
```

I am new to JavaScript and I am successful in getting values which I have to convert to the JavaScript Object but I am getting correct output . The lines which I have commented did not gave me correct result . Please give some hint . Thanks in advance !!

Comment: How does `{"10": 1, "20": 3, "30": 1, "31": 1}` relate to the array above it?

Comment: what condition apply to convert from the first array to the object ?

Comment: We should guess the error? Or maybe you will be kind and post error's text?

Comment: @DominicTobias numbers are values of `NotificationItems`.

Comment: I am not getting error but I am not getting correct output also

Comment: "but still I am getting error" Who wrote this?

Comment: @@DominicTobias you are correct

Comment: @u_mulder soory for this I will edit it

Comment: "into this array" `{"10": 1, "20": 3, "30": 1, "31": 1}` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @phuzi yes it is object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const result = data.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[NotificationItems[v.slug.toUpperCase()]] = (v.channels.sms ? 1 : 0) +
                                               (v.channels.email ? 2 : 0);
  return a;
}, {});
```

Or to make it completely dynamic:

```
const result = data.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[NotificationItems[v.slug.toUpperCase()]] = Object.keys(v.channels).reduce((b, w) => b + (v.channels[w] ? NotificationChannels[w.toUpperCase()] : 0), 0)
  return a;
}, {});
```

**Full snippet:**

```js
const NotificationChannels = {
  SMS: 1, // 01
  EMAIL: 2 // 10
  // BOTH: 3
};

const NotificationItems = {
  INVOICE: 10,
  PAYMENT: 20,
  MANUAL_REMINDER: 30,
  AUTOMATIC_REMINDER: 31
};

const data = [{
    slug: 'invoice',
    display: 'Invoice',
    channels: {
      sms: true,
      email: false
    }
  },
  {
    slug: 'payment',
    display: 'Payment',
    channels: {
      sms: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  {
    slug: 'manual_reminder',
    display: 'Manual Reminder',
    channels: {
      sms: true,
      email: false
    }
  },
  {
    slug: 'automatic_reminder',
    display: 'Automatic Reminder',
    channels: {
      sms: true,
      email: false
    }
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[NotificationItems[v.slug.toUpperCase()]] = Object.keys(v.channels).reduce((b, w) => b + (v.channels[w] ? NotificationChannels[w.toUpperCase()] : 0), 0)
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```